# Reliable free offline dictionary for Android

Tags: gratis, android, offline, dictionary

I'm having difficulty with pronouncing words or phrases in British or American English. I wanted to install or download a dictionary software.

I went to Play store and found [WordWeb Audio Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordwebsoftware.android.wordwebaudio&hl=en), but it's not available for free.

I have found many online dictionary for free, but not found offline dictionaries.

Comment: Just saw it today, but haven't tried it myself: [aePronunciation](https://github.com/suragch/aePronunciation) describes itself as "Android app for learning IPA and American English pronunciation", which seems exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I need British and American English pronounciation offline dictionary for free. I'm sorry, I think nobody is so kind to share an app or software for free.

Comment: @yubraj Guilt-tripping software developers? That's funny.

Answer (score 2):

Check out My Word List. It is a free android app with an offline dictionary, and you can also hear the pronunciations in Britain and American English.

Links:

Free Version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

Disclaimer: I am the developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can download languages in [Google Translate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate)

> • Offline: Translate 52 languages when you have no Internet